# How access variables in update function of mutation component?

Tags: javascript, react-apollo

When I use react-apollos  component's update function the data parameter is sometimes empty and I cannot figure out what it depends on. Currently, I try to update a value in the @client cache, perhaps this is a cache only problem.

I tried to research, but all examples seem to just presume that the data parameter is filled with data, but do not explain how to get it there.

```
const SOME_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation someMutation($toggleProp: Boolean!) {
    someMutation(toggleProp: $toggleProp) @client {
       someProp {
         toggleProp
       }
    }
  }
`;

<Mutation
mutation={SOME_MUTATION}
update={(cache, data) => console.log(data)} // => { data: {} }
>
{someMutation => (
  <SomeComponent onClick={() => someMutation({variables: { toggleProp: true } })} />
)}
</Mutation>
```

I would expect to have toggleProp available in the update data parameter, but instead it's just an empty object.

Comment: are `someProp` and `toggleProp` defined in schema. have you defined resolver for them? if not you need to define resolver for each `type` that you have defined in your schema. this is all for server side. getting null is not related to `react-apollo`. first try your api in `playground` or `graphiql` whatever you're using.

Comment: I didn't set up a schema as the documentation says it is optional. I also thought resolvers are optional and are interchangeable with the update function (so either use resolvers or update function). Does an update function require a resolver?

Comment: does your mutation run fine in `graphiql` ? have you tried it? also schema is needed for every operation and data that you want. its not optional. maybe it is optional for something else. not sure.

Comment: Not sure if I mentioned this enough but this case is client-side only. So I have an initial local state and I only try to update this on the client-side.

Comment: sorry my bad. didn't see the new edit ... have you checked this out? https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/caching/#inmemorycache

Comment: Yes, I did. Your hint with the resolver was very helpful. Now I added a resolver function: someMutation: (_root, variables) => variables. As a result I have the variables in the data parameter, but I constantly get errors that there are missing fields even though all fields are included. Did I miss anything out on the resolver function?

Comment: check this out. this shows how to implement a local resolver in detail: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/essentials/local-state/#updating-local-state

Comment: Thanks @kcsujeet, I solved it with resolver instead of update function. Now everything works fine.